# android register a permanent Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to create a BroadcastReceiver which performs certain task immediately each time the device boots up. Also, when a certain button is clicked, the receiver should stop starting on boot. Can someone help me to manage that?

Comment: What have you tried? There are lots of questions on this, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Comment: issue is to stop BroadcastReceiver when  certain button is clicked. this  certain button is in your application or any other?

Comment: my app only. Thanks guys, Ralgha's solution seems to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to solve the first part of your question is to make a `BroadcastReceiver` for it and declare it in your Manifest as:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The `QUICKBOOT_POWERON` is necessary for some devices that don't send the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.  HTC devices like to use the quickboot one instead.

For the second part of your question, there are a few different ways you could accomplish this.  You could simply set a value in `SharedPreferences` that your receiver checks every time it fires, and exit immediately if the value dictates such.

You could also disable the receiver in code:

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting( 
    new ComponentName( this, MyBootReceiver.class ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP );
```

You can enable it using the same method:

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting( 
    new ComponentName( this, MyBootReceiver.class ),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP );
```

I am unsure of the persistence of this method.  I use it in one of my apps, but it's not for a boot receiver, and it doesn't have to persist across boots.  You'll have to experiment with it if you want to go that route.