# How can I always keep my broadcast receiver alive?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-broadcast

I have a broadcast receiver on my app. But I want to listen push notification on everytime I mean when phone restarted I want to start my receiver **OR** when a user clean all application I need to restart my broadcast receiver again. It is possible? How it can be possible?

Comment: What do you mean of restart receiver? Static receivers always listens intents.

Comment: but when my phone restart it does not listen anymore.

Comment: For push notifications You are using GCM jars or PlayServices for android?

Comment: Add you code here. And what are you trying to do?

Comment: I use parse.com to push notification. It works fine. But when I restart my phone it does not listen anymore untill I open my app again

Comment: So you can lunch service in your app when phone system boot. In the service you can make needed action (lunch broadcast or smth).  this link can be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385231/android-broadcastreceiver-auto-run-service-after-reboot-of-device

Comment: I think this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959410/android-register-a-permanent-broadcast-receiver